# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in PIVOT function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below query to get the employee salary monthwise by using the PIVOT, but it throws an SQL command not properly ended. please verify and fix it

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT EMPID, MONTH, SALARY
    FROM SALARY
) PIVOT(SALARY AS SALARY FOR (MONTH) IN ('Jan','Feb','Mar'))
ORDER BY EMPID;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT EMPID, MONTH, SALARY
   FROM SALARY
   PIVOT(SALARY AS SALARY FOR MONTH IN ('Jan','Feb','Mar'))
   ORDER BY EMPID;
```

[Reference](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)

Comment: this query working fine   {SELECT * FROM (SELECT EMPID, MONTH, SALARY FROM SALARY) PIVOT(SUM(SALARY) AS SALARY FOR (MONTH) IN ('Jan','Feb','Mar')) ORDER BY EMPID;}